# How to change the implementing class when using annotations with Spring?

Tags: spring

I'm used to Spring with xml configuration. With xml, I can have one main implementation and one test implementation for a class, so that the test implementation will be used for JUnit tests, how can I do this with annotations ? Cause it looks like the implementation is already chosen in the "@qualifier" annotation ?

Let's take an example :

```
<bean id="myService" class="example.Service" />
<bean id="myHibernateDao" class="example.HibernateDao" />
<bean id="myStubDao" class="example.StubDao" />
```

In xml config, I can have this in src/main/resources :

```
<bean id="myService" class="example.Service">
  <ref="myHibernateDao" />
</bean>
```

And this in src/test/resources :

```
<bean id="myService" class="example.Service">
  <ref="myStubDao" />
</bean>
```

How can I do this with annotations, if I have already declared @Qualifier("myHibernateDao") into my service class ?

Comment: Look into profiles and `@Profile`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment above and in [spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), you can do this via `@Profile` annotation.

Please find a sample config from the example below,

DataConfig.java

```
interface DataConfig {

    DataSource dataSource();

}
```

StandaloneDataConfig .java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class StandaloneDataConfig implements DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql")
                .build();
    }
}
```

JndiDataConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class JndiDataConfig implements DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

TransferServiceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class TransferServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataConfig dataConfig;

    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new DefaultTransferService(accountRepository(), feePolicy());
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountRepository accountRepository() {
        return new JdbcAccountRepository(dataConfig.dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public FeePolicy feePolicy() {
        return new ZeroFeePolicy();
    }

}
```

Setting bean profile to an application context

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("dev");
ctx.register(TransferServiceConfig.class, StandaloneDataConfig.class,
        JndiDataConfig.class);
ctx.refresh();
```

Since the bean profile has been set to `Dev`, The `TransferServiceConfig`will be injected with `StandaloneDataConfig`

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do the same thing with `@Configuration` classes.

### Production Setup

Let's assume you have many different DAO implementations that might or might not implement a common interface (it doesn't matter). Let's further assume that `MyServiceDao` is the concrete implementation that your `Service` class needs.

Write the following configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Service myService(MyServiceDao dao) {
        return new Service(dao);
    }

}
```

-

```
@Configuration
public class MyProductionServiceDaoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyServiceDao myServiceDao() {
        return new MyServiceDao();
    }

}
```

Methods in `@Configuration` classes that are annotated with `@Bean` are eligible for Spring's auto-wiring. In the `MyServiceConfiguration` above, Spring will use the type of the method parameter to find a matching bean. If you include `MyProductionServiceDaoConfiguration` when creating the Spring context, this will be the instance of `MyServiceDao` that `myServiceDao()` created.

### Test Setup

In your tests, you want to replace `MyServiceDao` with a stub. The stub needs to extend `MyServiceDao` so that Spring can find the right bean based on types. Let's call the stub `MyServiceDaoStub`. Whether you create it using a library like Mockito (which can also create stubs, not just mocks) or actually write an extension of `MyServiceDao` is up to you.

Instead of including `MyProductionServiceDaoConfiguration` in your Spring configuration, use the following class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyTestServiceDaoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyServiceDao myServiceDao() {
        return new MyServiceDaoStub();
    }

}
```

In your test use `@ContextConfiguration` to load the test setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyServiceConfiguration.class, MyTestServiceDaoConfiguration.classs })
public class MyServiceTest {

    // your tests

}
```

### Using @Autowired

Spring will also process `@Autowired` annotations in objects returned from `@Bean` annotated methods. If your `Service` looks like this:

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceDao dao;

    // more code

}
```

you can change the `myService()` method to:

```
@Bean
public Service myService() {
    return new Service();
}
```

Comment: Your answer is the most interesting because it's clause to my example. Though, I don't want to pass the dao in the service constructor, how can I do this with configuration class ? Also, in your example, u have 3 implicit bean names "hibernateDao" "myHibernateDao" "stubDao", why would autowiring take place ?

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it : in a real app, I would have dozens of classes implementing "HibernateDao", how to make Spring discriminate between them ? Also service.setHibernateDao(...) means I can't use @Autowire with java based config ?

Comment: Updated my answer again. Spring will process `@Autowired` annotations in `@Bean`s. If you have multiple classes that implement `HibernateDao` use the concrete class for the fields annotated with `@Autowired`. As mentioned in my answer, Spring will match beans based on types.

Comment: If I use the concrete class in my service, it will be the same concrete class for tests and for prod. I'm sorry, your answers are mainly getting me confused for 2 reasons : first, u assume my stub/mock dao will inherit my main hibernateDao which of course will never be the case u need to define one common interface or abstract class to make your example clear. Second, u are describing "java based config", I was talking about pure annotations. Maybe the answer was "u can't do this with annotations, u need explicit config (xml or java based)" ?

Comment: 1) Why would that never be the case? You can easily create `StubDao` as a mock of `HibernateDao` using a mocking library like Mockito. In any case, I updated my answer to use a common interface. 2) The whole point of Java based config is to rely purely on annotations. As you can see in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so now let's say we have dozens of dao implementing "DaoInterface", where is the selection of the right dao implementation in your example ? (Not to launch a debate, but my stub dao was intended to be a stub, not a mock http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

Comment: I understand that "java based" config provide the same possibilities as xml config. What about your last example with pure annotations and "@Autowired", you are not showing the implementation selection. Let's say MyServiceDao is an interface implemented by MyServiceDaoRealImpl, MyServiceDaoStub1Impl and MyServiceDaoStub2Impl, how do I indicate one impl for prod and one impl for test in pure annotations ?

Comment: You need to have different `@Configuration` classes as I (tried to) explain in my answer, just as you would need to have different XML configuration files when using traditional XML configuration. `@Configuration` classes are basically the equivalent of XML configuration files.

Comment: So, in a few words, the use of "@Qualifier" is only possible when u have only one implementation, is that what you say ? Or is the config (xml or java based) overriding "@Qualifier" ?

Comment: Not at all, that wouldn't make much sense. But you don't need `@Qualifier` in the example described above, because Spring is able to distinguish the beans by type.